# Заполнение столбца значениями из другой таблицы в случайном порядке sql

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Profile (user_id, media_source, country)
SELECT 
    (random() *10^3) as user_id,
     now() - interval '15 minute' *  random() as media_source,


 ( SELECT country_id FROM country 
        ORDER BY RANDOM()
        LIMIT 1
      )   as country  


 from generate_series (1, 100) AS g(i)                               
;
```

Как сделать так, чтобы для столбца country выбиралось случайное значение для каждой сгенерированной строки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Profile (user_id, media_source, country)
SELECT 
    (random() *10^3) as user_id,
     now() - interval '15 minute' *  random() as media_source,


 ( SELECT country_id FROM (SELECT random() AS random_in, country_id FROM country) AS country 
        ORDER BY random_in*random_out
        LIMIT 1
      )   as country  


 from random() AS random_out, generate_series (1, 100) AS g(i)                               
;
```